# Thread priorities no effect

Tags: java, concurrency, starvation

I'm writing a starvation simulation in Java. However, when I run it, it simply doesn't work almost any time. I'm working on MacOS. The code is like:

```
public class StarvationNew {
private static SharedObject sharedObject = new SharedObject(); // to jest ten obiekt (operacja) na ktorym sie blokuje
private static volatile boolean isActive = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Worker(), "Thread_1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Worker(), "Thread_2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Worker(), "Thread_3");

    t1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    t2.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    t3.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();


    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    isActive = false;

}

private static class Worker implements Runnable {
    private int runCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isActive) {
            sharedObject.playOperation();
            runCount++;
        }
        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended with: " + runCount);
        System.out.println("--------");
    }
}
```

}

and the SharedObject just simulates long running operations looks like this:

```
public class SharedObject {
    public synchronized void playOperation() {
        try {
            // long operations
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(150);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder what is the mistake in this code.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I know that Java prorites are only hints for OS but in my case hardly any run of compiled code shows Starvation of Thread 3. Is the code concept for simulating starvation ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to keep in mind when working with Java threads.

1. The rules for thread priorities are highly system-dependent. When
   the virtual machine relies on the thread implementation of the host
   platform, the thread scheduling is at the mercy of that thread
   implementation.
2. **Rule of thumb**:  At any given time, the highest priority thread is
   running. However, this is not guaranteed. **The thread scheduler may
   choose to run a lower priority thread to avoid starvation**. For this
   reason, use thread priority only to affect scheduling policy for
   efficiency purposes. Do not rely on it for algorithm correctness.
3. What happens if there is more than one runnable thread with the same
   (highest) priority? One of the highest priority threads gets picked.
   It is completely up to the thread scheduler how to arbitrate between
   threads of the same priority. The Java programming language gives no
   guarantee that all of the threads get treated fairly.

The above being said, I don't see anything abnormal with the following output on my Windows 10 (Java 8) machine:

```
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_1
Thread_3
--------
Thread_1 ended with: 34
--------
--------
Thread_2
Thread_3 ended with: 1
--------
--------
Thread_2 ended with: 1
--------
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/priority.html) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for help. I ran my code on Windows and it works fine, but is this code a 'good' example of Starvation or should I think about something else?

Comment: @TomKo1 Not sure what do **you** mean by "starvation". Please define it.

Comment: I mean that one greedy thread is occupying shared resource providing (sometimes they gain access) others from accesing to it. My lecturer once turn Down my code because I used synchronized Keyword in fron to Method name. The starvation is described Here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html

Comment: @TomKo1 I think it's a good example, Thread 1 makes the other threads starving.